# Adding prometheus jmx agent jar to JIB build

Tags: java, kotlin, kubernetes, prometheus, jib

I need to add the "**jmx_prometheus_javaagent**" jar to JIB build but I get the following error when I deploy the application:

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /srv/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.16.1.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

I have added the jar and a config file in the required directory and these are the relevant change I did in my **build.gradle.kts**:

```
val jibExtraDir = file("$buildDir/jib-extra")
val jibAppRoot = "/srv"

val copyJmxPrometheusJavaAgent by tasks.registering(Copy::class) {
    val jarName = "jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.16.1.jar"
    val configName = "jmx_prometheus_config.yaml"
    from("${project.projectDir.absolutePath}/resources/jmx-prometheus")
    into("$jibExtraDir/$jibAppRoot")
    doLast {
        // Required for reproducible builds.
        file("$jibExtraDir/$jibAppRoot/$jarName").setLastModified(0)
        file("$jibExtraDir/$jibAppRoot/$configName").setLastModified(0)
    }
}

subProjects {
    plugins.withType<JibPlugin>().configureEach {
        container {
            jvmFlags = listOf(
                           "-javaagent:$jibAppRoot/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.16.1.jar=8099:$jibAppRoot/jmx_prometheus_config.yaml"
                       )
        }
        tasks.withType<JibTask> {
            dependsOn(":copyJmxPrometheusJavaAgent")
        }
}
```

This is my **jmx_prometheus_config.yaml**:

```
---
lowercaseOutputName: true
whitelistObjectNames: [
    "java.lang:type=Memory",
    "java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,*"
]
```

The error message states that the JAR manifest is missing. But since the directory structure I added in the JIB looks alright, I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are copying the agent files from `resources/jmx-prometheus/*` into `<project root>/build/jib-extra/srv`, but that just ends there. Jib isn't putting those files into a built image.

Since the default Jib "extra directories" is `src/main/jib`, technically, you can simply copy the files into `src/main/jib/...`. However, I assume you don't want to check in the files into the source directory, so you will probably want to configure the Jib extra directory like this:

```kotlin
        container {
            jvmFlags = ...
        }
        extraDirectories {
            paths {
                path {
                    setFrom("$jibExtraDir")
                }
            }
        }
```

or

```kotlin
extraDirectories.paths = "$jibExtraDir"
```

See this [doc](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin#adding-arbitrary-files-to-the-image) for more information about the `extraDirectories` configuration.

Also, here's a [Jib sample](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/examples/java-agent/build.gradle) that dynamically downloads and copies a Java agent.

---

Tip: [`dive`](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) is a very handy tool to inspect the contents of a build image. Use it to verify whether the files are correctly copied into an image.